# Xna 2d texture antialiasing

Tags: xna, 2d, antialiasing

I've got a problem with drawing 2D texture in xna 4.0.
My program generates terrain texture:

[image: Generated terrain]

[image: Surface]

The problem is in rough surface of my texture (dark-blue) that is generated by-pixel. Is there any method to smooth my texture without scaling it? (SamplerState didn't help me)

A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21666/how-would-i-go-about-using-fxaa-in-xna